# Calculate Standard working hours for specific date range by passing in time and out time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate the standard working hours by passing in time and out time between a specific date range.

I've tried the following :

```
select trunc(hrs*24)||':'||ltrim(to_char(round((((hrs*24) - trunc(hrs*24))*60),2),'09'))
from (
select 8 * (to_date('1730','HH24:MI') - to_date('0900','HH24:MI')) hrs from dual

);
```

where "8" is the number of days

but it's returning **67:60** when I pass 8 number of days while it is working fine for other number of days.

It should return 68:00 i.e. 68 hours and 00 minutes of the total working hours for 8 days.

How can I resolve this?

**Update :**

Actual method used in Attendance System to get Total Standard hours count:

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_std_hrs (stdin IN VARCHAR2,stdout in VARCHAR2,from_dt in DATE,to_dt in date)
RETURN CHAR AS
--
hrs   number;
--
BEGIN
--
     select count(*) * (to_date(stdout,'HH24:MI') - to_date(stdin,'HH24:MI'))
  into   hrs
  from   olpcdc.calendar
  where  date_time_start between from_dt and to_dt
  and    to_char(date_time_start,'dy') not in ('sat','sun')
  and    not exists (select 1 from OLPCDC.HOLIDAYS 
                                where trunc(date_time_start) between trunc(holiday_frmdt) and trunc(holiday_todt));
 return(trunc(hrs*24)||':'||ltrim(to_char(round((((hrs*24) - trunc(hrs*24))*60),2),'09')));                               
--
END;
```

Comment: Please show us some sample table data and your expected output.  Even if a guru were to attempt an answer, right now I don't think this question would be very useful to anyone else.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added the actual method where I'm using the query